# how to use cleveref package to get Fig. in latex

Tags: latex

When I use the cleveref package in latex, if I use `\cref{fig1}`, I got
*fig. 1* and if I use `\Cref{fig1}` I got *Figure 1*. But what I really 
want is *Fig. 1*. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am back to answer my own question. it can be done by the commands,

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\Crefformat{figure}{#2Fig.~#1#3}
\Crefmultiformat{figure}{Figs.~#2#1#3}{ and~#2#1#3}{, #2#1#3}{ and~#2#1#3}
```

from the "The cleveref package" at TeXdoc.net